# setting color for null values plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

I want to set a custom color for missing values in plotly javascript and cannot figure out how.

In the following example the missing value is represented by `null` in the array given to the `color` property.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.js" ></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%" ></div>
<script>
    var color_scale = [[0, "#ff0000"], [1, "#00ff00"]];
    var trace = {
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
        marker: {
            color: [1, 2, 3, null],
            colorscale: color_scale
        },
        mode: 'markers',
        type: 'scatter'
    };

    var data = [trace];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what missing values are you referring to? If they are missing, they won't be plotted - how do you color something that is not in the picture? Please be more precise on what you want to achieve

Comment: the `null` value for color should have a color that is not part of the color scale and I want to be able to specify this value.

Comment: the `run code snippet` button does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to break out of the defined color-scale from `#ff0000` to `#00ff00`?

in the `marker.color`-array, you can also specify strings, which can contain any way of defining a color: hex-notation, name, rgb, ...

So this should be along the lines of what you are looking for:

`color: [1,2,3,'#0000ff'],`

Comment: it works, I hoped there was a more elegant solution to that. Like setting `[null, '#0000ff']` in the color scale or setting `marker:{'missing.color': '#0000ff'}`. Thanks!